# Animation only works in keyPresed when key is held down?

Tags: processing

I want to animation to keep running once the space bar is pressed but it only runs when I hold the key down. When the space bar is pressed again, I want it to stop running and it will alternate between moving and not moving as I press the space bar

Comment: Processing language which is a basic form of java

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `boolean` value to keep track of whether the animation should run or not. Set that boolean in the `keyPressed()` function, and check it in the `draw()` function. Something like this:

```
boolean move = false;
float x = 0;

void setup(){
  size(500, 100);
  ellipseMode(RADIUS);
}

void keyPressed(){
  move = !move;
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  ellipse(x, 50, 10, 10);

  if(move){
   x++; 
  }
}
```

For future reference, you'll be better off posting an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with a specific question. It's hard to answer general "how do I do this" type questions, but it's much easier to answer "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions.